# Not able to copy and paste multiple Components in SDL Web 8

Tags: web8

Users not able to copy and paste multiple Components and Pages in SDL Web 8. It is working fine for Administrator, but not for users.

Users are able to copy and paste single item but not multiple items.

Is this expected behavior, or can we change any configuration?

It is calling `QueryMultipleOperations.svc` and we are getting below result.

[image]

```
{"d":"
<tcm:MultipleOperations ID=\"tcm:0-27036-66048\" IsEditable=\"true\" xmlns:tcm=\"http:\/\/www.tridion.com\/ContentManager\/5.0\"
 xmlns:xlink=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/xlink\" 
 xmlns:i=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema-instance\">
 <tcm:Info>
 <tcm:VersionInfo>
 <tcm:CreationDate>2017-07-28T12:18:16<\/tcm:CreationDate>
 <tcm:RevisionDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00<\/tcm:RevisionDate>
 <\/tcm:VersionInfo>
 <\/tcm:Info>
 <tcm:Data><tcm:Title>ed70bd53-b5b4-48e3-9294-cf441ee5959b<\/tcm:Title>
 <tcm:Performer xlink:type=\"simple\" xlink:title=\"\user.test\" xlink:href=\"tcm:0-1016-65552\" description=\"user test\" \/>
 <tcm:Operations operationsDone=\"0\" operationsCount=\"2\" skipOnError=\"true\" xmlns:tcm=\"http:\/\/www.tridion.com\/ContentManager\/5.0\">
 <tcm:PasteItem>
 <tcm:Component xlink:type=\"simple\" xlink:href=\"tcm:xxx-690742\" xlink:title=\"tcm:xxx-690742\" xmlns:xlink=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/xlink\" \/>
 <tcm:Component xlink:type=\"simple\" xlink:href=\"tcm:xxx-690747\" xlink:title=\"tcm:xxx-690747\" xmlns:xlink=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/xlink\" \/>
 <\/tcm:PasteItem><\/tcm:Operations>
 <tcm:Active>true<\/tcm:Active>
 <\/tcm:Data>
 <\/tcm:MultipleOperations>"
 }
```

Could you please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try restarting the TcmBatchProcessor service. Not sure why, but this does seem to happen often.

Comment: The JSON response only shows that a batch has been created to copy/paste 2 Components. This batch should be picked up by the TcmBatchProcessor service. Is it running? If so, does it log anything in the Tridion event log?

Comment: Hi Rick Thanks for your answer, Yes it is running and it is not providing any logs in Tridion event log.

Comment: Add MTSUser in CME as an Administrator and try

Answer (score 2):

Try and run the batch processor service in debug mode:

- stop the batch processor service
- Using command prompt navigate to path "TridionHome"\bin
- run command TcmBatchProcessor.exe -d
- Try to copy and paste multiple items again, you should have the logs in the command prompt and hopefully the errors too!
  Try and solve whatever the problem is.

Comment: Super, nice troubleshooting tips!

Answer (score 1):

If you can perform single operations fine but not multiple (batch) operations, check that your `Tridion Content Manager Batch Processor service` is started on the Content Manager.

Also check the `administratorUserName` attribute's value for the `configuration/batching` node in your `Tridion.ContentManager.config.xml`